# Where does $_ come from in this Perl foreach loop?

Tags: perl

I found this in [Mail::IMAPClient](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-IMAPClient). Where does the `$_` in `$SEARCH_KEYS{ uc($_) }` come from?

```
sub _quote_search {
    my ( $self, @args ) = @_;
    my @ret;
    foreach my $v (@args) {
        if ( ref($v) eq "SCALAR" ) {
            push( @ret, $$v );
        }
        elsif ( exists $SEARCH_KEYS{ uc($_) } ) {
            push( @ret, $v );
        }
        elsif ( @args == 1 ) {
            push( @ret, $v );    # <3.17 compat: caller responsible for quoting
        }
        else {
            push( @ret, $self->Quote($v) );
        }
    }
    return @ret;
}
```

Comment: Looks like that should be $v. Sometimes what you see are bugs. :)

Comment: Because 8 out of 10 bugs that I find at the end are no bugs I am a little cautious.

Comment: Still leaves the 2/10 that are :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks to me like a typo where the author converted an anonymous for loop `foreach (@args)` to one with an explicit iterator variable `foreach my $v (@args)` and forgot to convert all the incidences of `$_` to `$v`.

You should probably file a bug against the distribution on CPAN.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is probably a bug, lets consider how this code behaves.

The value of `$_` will be determined by the current dynamic scope.  What this means is that `$_` will have whatever value (the dynamically scoped copy of) `$_` has in the calling subroutine.

So for example if I have:

```
for (1 .. 5 ) {
    foo();
    bar();
}

sub foo {
     print "\$_ = $_\n";
}

sub bar {

    for ( 'a' .. 'c' ) {
        foo();
    }
}
```

You get output like:

```
$_ = 1
$_ = a
$_ = b
$_ = c
$_ = 2
$_ = a
$_ = b
$_ = c
...
```

It gets a little weirder in Perl 5.10 and up, where a lexical `$_` exists.

```
for (1 .. 5 ) {
    foo();
    bar();
}

sub foo {
     print "\$_ = $_\n";
}

sub bar {
    my $_;
    for ( 'a' .. 'c' ) {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Run this and get:

```
$_ = 1
$_ = 1
$_ = 1
$_ = 1
$_ = 2
$_ = 2
$_ = 2
$_ = 2
```

As you can see, if this isn't a bug, it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Does the lexicaliced $_ keep the value?
This doesn't work: $_ = 10; { my $_; say; }

Comment: Ok, maybe it's the foo, that keeps the value.

Comment: @Eric, not really, but 99% of my work needs to be Perl 5.8 compatible.  It is important to consider when looking at the posted code.

Comment: @sid, `$_` is a global variable that gets a new dynamic scope (like you get via `local`) in each for loop.  So `foo()` is just printing whatever value is in what `$_` points to at the time it is called.  `bar` localizes `$_`, and so it now points to a different value.  Take a look at Coping With Scoping.  It goes into detail on how dynamic scoping works.  http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html#Just_the_FAQs_Coping_with_Scopi